PHP decrypt function corresponding to Java encrypt function
Can someone give me the PHP code corresponding to this Java function ?
public String deciphering(String text,String key) {

    String[] parts = text.split(":");
    byte[] iv = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[0]);
    byte[] encryptedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1]);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(key), spec);

    byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
    return new String(decryptedText);
}

private SecretKey getSecretKey(String key) {
    return new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM_TYPE);
}

ALGORITHM = AES/GCM/NoPadding 
ALGORITHM_TYPE = AES

Thans for advance !
Franck.
Here is my current PHP function that returns always "not ok" :)
function deciphering($text, $key) {

    list($ivBase64, $encryptedTextBase64) = explode(":", $text);

    $iv = base64_decode($ivBase64);
    $encryptedText = base64_decode($encryptedTextBase64);

    $cipher = 'aes-128-gcm';

    if (openssl_decrypt($encryptedText, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv)) {
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "not ok";
    }
}
deciphering($text, $key);


In the Java code, ciphertext and authentication tag are concatenated. You must separate them in the PHP code and pass them individually, see openssl_decrypt(), the parameters data and tag.

Judging by that algorithm spec in the Java code you probably also want OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING as well.

PHP/OpenSSL automatically disables padding for stream cipher modes such as GCM, so that OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING does not need to be set explicitly.

Modify your PHP code slightly and pay attention to the TAG_LENGTH_BIT constant.
const ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-gcm';
const TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128;

function deciphering($text, $key){
    $parts = explode(":", $text);
    if (count($parts) !== 2) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid input format");
    }

    $iv = base64_decode($parts[0]);
    $encryptedText = base64_decode($parts[1]);

    $tag = substr($encryptedText, -TAG_LENGTH_BIT / 8);
    $ciphertext = substr($encryptedText, 0, -TAG_LENGTH_BIT / 8);

    $decryptedText = openssl_decrypt(
        $ciphertext,
        ALGORITHM,
        $key,
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
        $iv,
        $tag
    );

    if ($decryptedText === false) {
        throw new Exception("Decryption failed");
    }

    return $decryptedText;
}

